# What's the proper way to format an Objective-C method signature with arguments?

Tags: objective-c, methods, initialization, nsarray

I'm a web designer/developer who has finally decided to try his hand at Objective-C. I strongly believe in standards and adhering to any guidelines, formats, or unwritten rules set forth by a language, instead of trying to shoehorn my own idea of how it should be done or use my own methods (pun not intended, but I'll go with it). In other words, I'm open to writing code with `camelCaseVarNames` or `underscore_var_names`; I just like to know what the "generally accepted" way things are done in the said language.

Anyway, I'd like to know the proper way of writing an Objective-C method — especially when extending an existing class. And mind you, I'm taking baby steps, so I'm not worrying about MVC design patterns or any of that "separation of concerns" hoo-hah right now. I'm working in the default `AppDelegate` implementation file (yeah, I'm a badass). I like to think it's the equivalent of writing a bunch of styles in the `<head>` of an HTML file when learning CSS; I'm just trying to see what this button does and what that button does. Make sense?

Okay, here's a scenario. Say you'd like to write a simple method that checks to see if a view is of a certain class. I'm sure there are plenty of ways to do this (and maybe every `NSObject` has this ability without the need for such a function), but humor me. Here's what I came up with (feel free to laugh):

```
- (BOOL)viewInstance:(id)view isOfClass(NSString *)className
{
    return ( [view class] == NSClassFromString(className) );
}
```

The problem I have is that `viewInstance:` by itself is pretty meaningless, and from what I've read, Objective-Cer's love superRichAndDescriptiveMethodNamesThatAreSelfDocumenting. With that said, the entire method name includes the second part — I'm assuming the second part is a named argument or parameter. So when read together, it actually makes a little sense. A real-world example of what I'm talking about is `NSColor`'s `colorWithDeviceRed` method. I went through the popup completion list 20 times before I realized that the `Red:` was the first parameter! The full declaration is:

`+ (NSColor *)colorWithDeviceRed:(CGFloat)red green:(CGFloat)green blue:(CGFloat)blue alpha:(CGFloat)alpha`

I guess I'm just confused as to when and/or how to name functions certain ways. Also, the initializing of objects confuses me. In the languages I know, I would create an array like this:

```
// JavaScript
var myArray = [ 1, 2, 3 ];

// PHP
$my_array = array( 1, 2, 3 );

// AppleScript
set myArray to { 1, 2, 3 }

// ActionScript
var myArray:Array = new Array( 1, 2, 3 );

// Python
my_array = [ 1, 2, 3 ]

// P.S. I add spaces between brackets because I'm a special boy, so no judgments.
```

In Objective-C, I don't ever know which to use:

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray new];
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray array];
NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:@[1,2,3]];
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:@[1,2,3]];
NSArray *myArray = @[1,2,3];
```

The array literal is the least scary to me because it makes the most sense coming from other languages. What I really don't understand is how in the above statements, there's an `initWithArray` method and an `arrayWithArray` method. Hmm. Does it call the same underlying method?

What *really* confuses me is this:

```
[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary)]
[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary) copyItems:(bool)]
```

After looking at the header file for NSDictionary, it looks to be two separate methods. I'm used to seeing optional arguments like:

```
function initWithObject(object, copyItems) {
    var obj = {};
    if ( copyItems ) {
        ...
    }
    return obj;
}
```

In my example, I would have an optional argument that when included would change the flow of the function. I'm probably completely wrong about the two methods thing, but from the little I know about Objective-C, that's what it looks like. However, I'm not going to run away just because I'm a little web biatch. Yeah, it's a bit scary that I can make threads go to sleep and write stuff like `NSTerminateNow`, but I think with the help of you folks, I could actually learn a thing or two. So, please, teach me!

My writing can be a bit "wordy" at times, so thanks for reading this far down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a little unfocused for Stack Overflow, but you do have some clear questions in there. For coding standards, start with a read of [Apple's guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html) and look at Apple source code. Try to always read methods with their full signatures. `NSColor colorWithDeviceRed:green:blue:alpha:` -- this is the way the compiler understands them.

The initializing of collections is a bit of relic now that ARC handles release/retain, basically using the "init" format would return a retained object and the class methods `[NSArray array]` would return an autoreleased one. I would use `@[ ]` since it is short and clear.

With the dictionary instantiation question, initializing one dictionary with another makes it such that the objects contained in A are now also contained in B. If you actually want copies of the object contained in A to go into B, `initWithDictionary:copyItems:` will perform a (shallow) copy of those items.

```
NSMutableString *someString = [@"abc" mutableCopy];
NSDictionary *a = @{ @"key" : someString };
NSDictionary *b1 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:a];
NSDictionary *b2 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:a copyItems:YES];

[someString appendString:@"def"];
// b1[@"key"] == abcdef
// b2[@"key"] == abc
// Note also that b1[@"key"] will be a mutablestring, b2[@"key"] will not
```

Generally you do not need to copy unless you know you need to copy. Good luck!

Comment: You left the final colon off of `-[NSColor colorWithDeviceRed:Green:Blue:Alpha:]` and `-initWithDictionary:copyItems:`.

Comment: Hey, @ben and @ken, it's Ben. Thanks, fellas! Sorry for not focusing the question(s?) better. When I'm in code-mode, it's hard for me to get out any coherent thoughts. Although, Ben, you did a good job of sifting through my drivel. Everything seemed so foreign at the time, but after working with it since then, things are starting to click. `[benFlynnReceiverObject sendMessage:@"I'm gettin' the hang of it now. See?"` Thanks again.